# Why use WCSF(Web Client Software Factory) for building asp.net web applications?

Tags: wcsf

WCSF is a software factory recommended from microsoft for developing web based applications. I feel that some thought is required on below before commiting to a software foctory:

- What is it?
- What are different features of it?
- How it will improve the productivity?
- How it will help in delivering on time with quality?
- Are there any limitations/cons to it?
- Are there any better alternatives to it?

Please help me in answering above questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx)

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=websf&DownloadId=3727](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=websf&DownloadId=3727)

> The Web Client Software Factory (WCSF)
>   provides a set of guidance for
>   architects and developers building
>   enterprise Web applications. The
>   factory includes samples, reusable
>   code and a guidance package which
>   automates key development tasks from
>   within Visual Studio.
>
> Using the Web Client Software Factory
>   assets, developers can create
>   Composite Web applications composed of
>   independently developed and deployed
>   modules. These modules are dynamically
>   brought together at runtime into a
>   common shell. Additionally the factory
>   includes support for ASP.NET AJAX thus
>   providing users with a richer and more
>   responsive user experience.

From [here](http://www.codeplex.com/websf)

***Edit:***

There is a similar article here in SO.

[Is .NET WCSF the way to go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170799/is-net-wcsf-the-way-to-go)